# angular 2 ng-charts cannot get value from table to chart

Tags: angular

i can not get value from table into chart graphic, i am trying to use input, but it doesnt work correctly. I cant understant how to get value from one component to other.
Im tryig to do like this, i use @input in my child component with charts:

```
@Input()
    set newInput(newInput:number) {
        if(<0)
            this._newInput=0;
        else if(newInput>100)
            this._newInput=100;
        else
            this._newInput= newInput;
  }
  get newInput() { return this._newInput; }
}
```

and in parent component.html i use that:

```
<charts-component [newInput]="newInput"></charts-component>
```

I put that 2 components .ts and .html files in plnker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/hPHo9FhqxaLbjWiDQp2w?p=preview

Comment: your plunker is working?

Comment: no, its just code from 2 components, is it should working ?

Comment: if it is a working example it will be easy for us to help you further

Comment: yeah, now its working, but i delete all inputs cause it crash some way : https://plnkr.co/edit/hPHo9FhqxaLbjWiDQp2w?p=preview

Comment: i type what i did with inputs below in head-message, i want to get value from table (date, income, outcome and profit) . I mean one line of that chart will be income, other one is outcome and other is profit, 3 lines. Bottom line of chart is date